# How to filter OSM files based on tags using Osmosis?

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, osmosis

I am working with .osm files and am trying to filter entities based on tags. I need to view only entities containing both source and attribution tags. I used the following to successfully filter all source tags only:

```
osmosis --read-xml file = "northern_ireland.osm" --way-key-value keyValueList="source" 
--used node --write-xml northern_ireland_source.osm
```

From another tutorial, I've noticed that I would need to use a pipe: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.38

So I did the following:

```
osmosis --rx northern_ireland.osm --accept-ways source=* outPipe.0 = SOURCE
```

However, upon trying such code, I get a syntax error stating:

*Argument does not contain a name before the '=' (i.e. name = value).*

Any suggestions?

Comment: you might also try asking at the OSM forum: http://help.openstreetmap.org

Answer (score 3):

You cannot combine filter options (condition A && condition B).

What you *can* do is filter in two different steps - first keep only ways satisfying the *source* condition and then filter the first step's result using the *attribution* condition.

E.g.:

```
./bin/osmosis --rx file=ireland.osm --tf accept-ways source=* --un --wx step1.osm

./bin/osmosis --rx file=step1.osm --tf accept-ways attribution=* --un --wx result.osm
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't help you with reading OSM files locally, but you might try your query through the new MapQuest XAPI - http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/xapi.  I suspect it might give you back the info you need.